# simple php code not working with ternary operator

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I'm quite a beginner when it comes to the ternary operators, never worked with them before.

Code (it was simplified)

```
$output2 = '
<div>
    <div>
        <span>test text1</span>
        <div>
            '.(1 == 1) ? "yes" : "no" .'
            <span>test text 2</span>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>';
echo $output2;
```

So the problem is, this code only outputs "yes" (only the correct or false if statement)

I tried with `""` same problem, tried with different conditions, tried just outputing it, without variables. But the problem remains.

Thank you.

Sebastjan

Comment: Well.. 1 does in fact equal 1, so `yes` should be returned.

Comment: yes, but it only returns "yes" and no "test text1" and "test text2"

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Surround your ternary `if` with brackets, i.e.

```
$output2 = '
<div>
    <div>
        <span>test text1</span>
        <div>
            '.((1 == 1) ? "yes" : "no") .'
            <span>test text 2</span>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>';
echo $output2;
```

Answer (score 7):

In php ternary operator behaves strangely, in your case:

```
(1 == 1) ? "yes" : "no" .'<span>test text 2</span>...'
```

`yes` is considered the first result, and `"no" . <span>test text 2</span>...` is the second result. To avoid such behaviour always use brackets

```
((1 == 1) ? "yes" : "no") .'<span>test text 2</span>...' // works correctly
```

Answer (score 2):

[Alexander's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1509705/alexander-larikov) answer is correct, but I would go a little further and actually remove the ternary from the string.

```
$ternary = ($something == $somethingElse) ? "yes" : "no";

// Double brackets allows you to echo variables
//  without breaking the string up.
$output = "<div>$ternary</div>";

echo $output;
```

Doing it this way proves to be much easier to maintain, and reuse.

---

Here are [a few uses](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) for ternary operators. They're very powerful if you use them properly.